# How to suppress line number when calling warning() in a MATLAB function?

Tags: matlab, command-line, output, line, warnings

```
function myfunc(x)
    if x == 1
        display('x is equal to 1')
    else
        warning('Invalid input, default value 1 will be used')
    end
end
```

When x is not 1 gives:

```
Warning: Invalid input, default value 1 will be used 
> In myfunc (line 5)
```

Is it possible to suppress `> In myfunc (line 5)`?

Answer (score 3):

You can turn the backtrace off with:
`warning('off','backtrace');`

Your code, then, could look like this:

```
function myfunc(x)
    warning('off','backtrace')
    if x == 1
        display('x is equal to 1')
    else
        warning('Invalid input, default value 1 will be used')
    end
    warning('on','backtrace'); % added after @ Cris Luengo comment
end
```

The output is:

```
>> myfunc(1)
x is equal to 1
>> myfunc(2)
Warning: Invalid input, default value 1 will be used 
>>
```

Comment: Note that this will modify all the warnings output from this point on, it is not selective for the current function or the next warning only.

Comment: A convenient way to revert the settings is to store the `warning` options when you first change them. So `w = warning('off','backtrace');`. Then at the end of the function you can call `warning(w);` to set all of the original settings. This can slightly easer than remembering what to turn back on, especially if you make more than one change.

Answer (score 3):

If you don’t want stack traces in your warning, don’t use `warning`, just output your warning using `disp` (or `fprintf`):

```
disp('Warning: Invalid input, default value 1 will be used')
```

If you need to highlight the warning using orange text, you can use [this trick](https://undocumentedmatlab.com/articles/another-command-window-text-color-hack):

```
disp(['[', 8, 'Warning: Invalid input, default value 1 will be used]', 8])
```